# Bluemix - can't access blockchain services - 404 error

Tags: http-status-code-404, ibm-cloud, blockchain

I have deployed 3 blockchain-based demos from this site: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html

After one week I entered my Bluemix account and I got this error when trying to click on one of blockchain services or enter blockchain console:

> 404 Not Found: Requested route ('obc-service-broker-prod.mybluemix.net') does > not exist.

I can't delete apps bounded with blockchain. Will be grateful for advice how should I proceed to make blockchain demo apps working again.

Comment: Are you still experiencing an issue? The service was experiencing some issues when you posted this question. You can always see the latest status for the Bluemix platform, its services, and its runtimes at the following URL: http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus

Comment: the problem is still not solved. Its also impossible to open a blockchain service. I get something like; 'sorry but due to overwhelming demand we are currently at maximum capacity for our service... .... return to the bluemix dashboard and delete this service instance.' The problem is I cant delete it.

Comment: Please let us know how you have attempted to delete the service instance. To delete it, you can go to the dashboard, select the dashboard instance, click the gear icon on the top right of the service, and select Delete Service. Are you unable to see that option or select it? (I am posting this comment on behalf of a developer who does not have enough reputation points.)

Comment: Problem solved, now I hava access to blockchain service and I can to what I want. Additional note: Bluemix support informed me that they had shortage of resources and 'overwhelming' demand. @Bill, I tried to delete as you described. After I hit 'delete' I got a message that obc-service-broker-prod.mybluemix.net does not exist.